# What's the easiest way to generate forms using laravel and js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have form when user can add achievement.

So it looks like:

```
<form action="{{ action('SettingsController@addAchievementsSettings') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="date" placeholder=" " id="date-achievement" name="date_achievement" class="form-control">
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">What</label>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
   <input type="text" placeholder=" " id="what-achievement" name="what_achievement" class="form-control">
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
  <textarea rows="10" cols="30" class="form-control" id="description_achievement" name="description_achievement"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Add one more...</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

I want to generate another form if somebody click Add one more. How can I reach this and how to add everything to database? Sorry guys for not more code but I do not have any idea

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on making forms interactive with JavaScript?  If not, please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

from your question it seems a proper video / tutorial would help you more than just the answer.
for generation I personally use [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html).
a good site with lots of videos explaining almost everything in regards to laravel and building sites with it I recomment the laracasts site. 
to learn how to build and process forms with laravel I suggest [Laravel 5.4 from scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/)

specifically for working with forms: [Form request data](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/11) and [form validation](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/12)

Answer (score 0):

After creating your form and submitting your form , you have to validate your data  then you will call your model to insert your date in database, i suggest you eloquent to handle database request if you are using laravel